# Separate error message for Minimum and Maximum string length - MVC4 Data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation, data-annotations

Would someone please share their implementation of having separate error messages for minimum and maximum string length using data annotations in MVC?

It seems `StringLength` only allows a single error message a `MinLength`/`MaxLength` do not generate unobtrusive validation markup as they are not `IClientValidatable`

Although this seems like a very common requirement I cannot find an implementation on the web.

Comment: [Regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8184202/609176)

Comment: Will those generate unobtrusive validation attributes?

Comment: Yup, javascript will execute the regular expressions client side

Comment: Cool, feel free to answer the question then.

Comment: This should be done in 4.5 MinLength MaxLength attributes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx
In my case I needed RegEx for some other error message and min max separatedly but I cannot upgrade version so I need to do custom validation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `RegularExpression` data annotation for the minimum check and use the `StringLength` attribute for the maximum check. Javascript will execute regular expressions client side so they are nice and unobtrusive! You can only use one `RegularExpression` attribute per property, otherwise you could do both maximum and minimum using regular expression.

Minimum of 5 characters

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 5 characters required")]
```

Maximum of 50 characters

```
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximum {2} characters exceeded")]
```

Comment: Hey I just tried this and I can't use 2 it says duplicate attribute! lol I still need a solution :(

Comment: Ah. I knew they worked unobtrusively... What about using one of these for the minimum and `[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximum {2} characters exceeded")]` for the max?

Comment: Good idea :) I used StringLength(int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Minimum") for min and regex for max. thanks again

Comment: This fails when there is more than one line [RegularExpression(@"^[\s\S]{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 5 characters required")] will make it work for multiple lines

Comment: I personally don't think this is an appropriate answer, given that you may already be using a regex for something else (in my case a password field with a regex to check for specific characters).  I think the right approach is probably to extend StringLength or create your own attribute.

Answer (score 16):

Although it is not separate messages, this is what I did:

```
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Must be between {2} and {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
```

Comment: If you don't use [Required] and the string is empty, then MinimumLength is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
[StringLength(800, ErrorMessage = "<img src='/images/icon-info.png' /><p>The {0} must be between {2} and {1} characters long.</p>", MinimumLength = 6)]
```

This will display an image and also min and max length.