# String MinLength and MaxLength validation don't work (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Argussoft.BI.DAL.Domain.Users;

namespace Argussoft.BI.DAL.DTOs.UserDTOs
{
    public class CreateUserDto
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите логин")]
        [MaxLength(User.EmailLength, ErrorMessage = "Максимальная длина логина 40 символов")]
        [RegularExpression(User.NameRegularExpression, ErrorMessage = "Логин может содержать только латинские символы, дефисы, подчеркивания, точки")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите Email")]
        [MaxLength(User.EmailLength, ErrorMessage = "Максимальная длина адреса электронной почты 100 символов")]
        [RegularExpression(User.EmailRegularExpression, ErrorMessage = "Введите корректный адрес электронной почты")]
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите имя пользователя")]
        [MaxLength(User.FullNameLength, ErrorMessage = "Максимальная длина имени пользователя 100 символов")]
        [RegularExpression(User.NameRegularExpression, ErrorMessage = "Имя пользователя может содержать только латинские символы, дефисы, подчеркивания, точки")]
        public virtual string FullName { get; set; }

        public virtual int Role { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(User.PhoneRegularExpression, ErrorMessage = "Введите корректный номер телефона")]
        public virtual string Phone { get; set; }

        public virtual int Status { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите пароль")]
        [MinLength(User.PasswordMinLength, ErrorMessage = "Минимальная длина пароля 5 символов")]
        [MaxLength(User.PasswordMaxLength, ErrorMessage = "Максимальная длина пароля 20 символов")]
        [RegularExpression(User.PasswordRegularExpression, ErrorMessage = "Пароль может содержать только латинские символы, дефисы, подчеркивания, точки")]
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this form

```
@model Argussoft.BI.DAL.DTOs.UserDTOs.CreateUserDto

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateUser", "User", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccessCreateUser" }, new { id = "dialog_form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4>Добавить пользователя</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Name)">Логин</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "span3", id = "input_name" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Email)">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "span3", id = "input_email" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- FullName -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.FullName)">Имя пользователя</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "span3", id = "input_full_name" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Role -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Role)">Роль пользователя</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Role", (SelectList)ViewBag.Roles,new{id ="input_role"})
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Phone -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Phone)">Контактный телефон</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @class = "span3", id = "input_phone" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Status -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Status)">Статус пользователя</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Status", (SelectList)ViewBag.UserStatuses,new{id ="input_status"})
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Password -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Password)">Пароль пользователя</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "span3", id = "input_password" })
                    <br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="@Url.Action("UserIndex", "User")" class="btn">Отменить</a>
        <button type="submit" id="save_button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
}
```

User class:

```
public class User : BaseEntity 
{ 
    public const int NameLength = 40; 
    public const int PasswordMinLength = 5; 
    public const int PasswordMaxLength = 20; 
    public const int FullNameLength = 100; 
    public const int EmailLength = 100; 
    public const int PhoneLength = 40; //...
}
```

but my validation works only for `Required` and `RegularExpression` and doesn't work for `MinLength` and `MaxLength` and I don't get any error message in this case.

What can be a reason?

Comment: What is the value of User.EmailLength?

Comment: `public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        public const int NameLength = 40;
        public const int PasswordMinLength = 5;
        public const int PasswordMaxLength = 20;
        public const int FullNameLength = 100;
        public const int EmailLength = 100;
        public const int PhoneLength = 40; //...}`

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**[MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)** is used for the Entity Framework to decide how large to make a string value field when it creates the database.

From MSDN:

> Specifies the maximum length of array
>   or string data allowed in a property.

**[StringLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx)** is a data annotation that will be used for validation of user input.

From MSDN:

> Specifies the minimum and maximum
>   length of characters that are allowed
>   in a data field.

### **Non Customized**

Use `[String Length]`

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.{3,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 30 characters")]
```

> 30 is the Max Length 
> Minimum length  = 3

### **Customized StringLengthAttribute Class**

```
public class MyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public MyStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength)
        : base(maximumLength)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string val = Convert.ToString(value);
        if (val.Length < base.MinimumLength)
            base.ErrorMessage = "Minimum length should be 3";
        if (val.Length > base.MaximumLength)
            base.ErrorMessage = "Maximum length should be 6";
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    [MyStringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public String MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How can I set min and max values in this case?

Comment: Thank you, it works. But if I need to set different error messages for MinimumLength and MaximumLength, how can I do that?

Comment: I tried to use your Customized StringLengthAttribute Class, I don't get compilation errors, but it doesn't work again and I don't get any validation error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307385/customized-stringlength-validation-doesnt-work-asp-net-mvc4 What can be wrong?

Comment: you can post your model/view controller.

Comment: I post my model and view controller here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307385/customized-stringlength-validation-doesnt-work-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: directly mention it in view without model check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30013537/2218697)

Comment: [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")] should be 
[RegularExpression(@"^.{3,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")] 
if you want it to validate that its a minimum of 3 chars

Answer (score 9):

Try using this attribute, for example for password min length:

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Максимальная длина пароля 20 символов", MinimumLength = User.PasswordMinLength)]
```

Comment: If I need to set different error messages for MinimumLength and MaximumLength, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessageResourceName= "PasswordMustBeBetweenMinAndMaxCharacters", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource), MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Save resource like this

```
"ThePasswordMustBeAtLeastCharactersLong" | "The password must be {1} at least {2} characters long"
```

Answer (score 4):

This can replace the MaxLength and the MinLength

```
[StringLength(40, MinimumLength = 10 , ErrorMessage = "Password cannot be longer than 40 characters and less than 10 characters")]
```

Comment: vb.net sytax  <StringLength(20, MinimumLength:=5)>

Answer (score 3):

They do now, with latest version of MVC (and jquery validate packages). [mvc51-release-notes#Unobtrusive](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Unobtrusive)

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202431/244353) for pointing it out!