# Using parameter for StringLength attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, asp.net-membership

The code which is generally generated for a ASP.NET MVC 3 Membership, escpecially the property `NewPassword` of the class `ChangePasswordModel` looks roughly like:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength=6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display("Name = CurrentPassword")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

In order to to fill some information with external parameters I am using `RecourceType:`
*(In this case I am changing `OldPassword` and fill the attribute `Display` with some additional Data from a Resource*

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Account), Name = "ChangePasswordCurrent")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }
```

Back to `NewPassword`. **How can I substitute the `MinimumLenght` with `Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength`?** : My attempt:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength=Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength)] 
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(ResourceType=typeof(Account), Name= "ChangePasswordNew")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

This produces the error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/09ze6t76%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: As mentioned in the Error Description, you can't pass variable in String Length Attribute Minimum Parameter. BUT, **[You could write `val.Length < Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength` as mentioned in this post under Customized StringLengthAttribute Class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18276949/2015869)**

Comment: thanks. I just outsource the constant to my GlobalVariables class and everthing was fine. This appears to be the easiest way

Comment: @NiklasS. This is indeed the quickest way, +1

Answer (score 4):

Validation attributes must be compiled constants (like your error message states).  You could create you own ValidationAttribute that handles this minimum length for you.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be at least {1} characters long.";

    private readonly int _minCharacters = Membership.Provider.MinRequiredPasswordLength;
    public ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute() : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString, name, _minCharacters);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var valueAsString = value.ToString();
        return (valueAsString != null) && (valueAsString.Length >= _minCharacters);
    }
}
```

Then your view model could look like this (you could even get more fancy and add the max length part of your DataAnnotations in the ValidatePasswordLength attribute to remove that line)

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100)] 
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(ResourceType=typeof(Account), Name= "ChangePasswordNew")]
[ValidatePasswordLength]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```