# mvc3 maxLength input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

this may be kind of general but i want to limit the number of character inpit in an editorfor field.

```
@html.EditorFor(m=>m.id,new {@maxlength="10"})
```

This does not seem to work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.id,  new { maxlength="10" });
```

EditorFor uses the templates, which you can override yourself.  I don't think they take into account the attributes you pass in like this.  The TextBoxFox<> generates it in code, and should work fine.

Comment: And what if we need to combine. I must use editor for watermarks, and still need maxlength. here is my editor code `@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })` how can I get "max" from metadata?

Comment: You have to write your own metadata provider (possibly) and a custom helper that adds to HtmlOptions before rendering (a simple wrapper basically).

Answer (score 13):

I was able to get it working in IE11 using the EditorFor and using multiple attributes.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "width:100px", @maxlength="10" } })
```

Comment: Upvoting because this worked for me: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { maxlength=10 } })`

Answer (score 4):

In MVC3, this is better:

```
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 10 characters.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Specifies the minimum and maximum length of characters that are allowed in a data field.
as in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802739/2127493

Comment: That did not work for me, neither `MaxLength` nor `StringLength` added the attribute `maxlength`, instead I only got `data-val-length-max` and `data-val-maxlength-max`.

Comment: StringLength and MaxLength (DataAnnotation) are for jquery validate and needs javascript.