# Asp.net mvc dataannotation MaxLength validation does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc4 in my model i am using Maxlength attribute but it does not work for string.
Only Stringlength works anyone have same problem ? if had issue how to resolve ? it does not work for validate my field
Here is my code

(not working)

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(80)]
[DisplayName("Contact Name:")]
public string ContactName { get; set; }
```

(working)

```
[Required]
[StringLength(80)]
[DisplayName("Contact Name:")]
public string ContactName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I am not getting an error. Please provide the class ContactName is in.

Comment: I have not said I am getting Error .I have only said it does not works.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both Attributes are in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace

As per Microsoft Official Website `[MaxLength]` attribute in for Entity Framework 
because Entity Framework knows what can be the maximum length of the column in the database in your case(like **varchar(80)**)

> Specifies the maximum length of array or string data allowed in a property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute.aspx

As in one of you comment you have said you are not using Entity Framework in reply with **@jackncoke** so `[MaxLength(80)]` will not work

But in second case `[StringLength(80)]` is working because it does not have any dependency over Entity Framework.

SO `[StringLength(80)]` will work in both cases if you are using Entity Framework or without it

> Specifies the minimum and maximum length of characters that are allowed in a data field.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx

Answer (score 6):

`[MaxLength(80)]` change to `[StringLength(80)]` but looks like you beat me to it!

Your not the only one with this problem

[MaxLength Attribute not generating client-side validation attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801656/maxlength-attribute-not-generating-client-side-validation-attributes)

Comment: yes i know it works with [StringLength(80)] but my question is why not with [MaxLength(80)] ? Even accoridng to microsoft it is valid attibute but you are the first first guy for answer so +1 for you

Comment: I was just looking through old projects and I have never used it always used StringLength. So I been looking on the internet to see if anyone else had this sort of issue. I have seen people use it as i been searching.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: I have not used entity framework i am passing static data to my model..And it should not make any difference .I was curious if it does not work only for me or for others too..

Answer (score 3):

IN MVC4 MaxLength workd properly, i have to check it

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [MaxLength(5)]  //MaxLength worked properly.
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

[image]