# MaxLength attribute and unobtrusive validation

Tags: jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-5.1

If I add a `MaxLengthAttribute` to a property like this:

```
[MaxLength]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Notes { get; set; }
```

The markup is rendered like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: Notes" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Notes must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '-1'." data-val-maxlength-max="-1" id="Notes" name="Notes"></textarea>
```

and the validation result looks something like this:

[image]

This is obviously not the intended result. The text area should allow A LOT more characters than '-1'.

I can think of multiple ways of addressing this (e.g. removing the attribute via jQuery, manually updating the rule with javascript, etc).

What is the **most elegant way** of addressing this issue? Is this a bug with MVC/Validator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801656/maxlength-attribute-not-generating-client-side-validation-attributes

Comment: No, not the same problem. This issue can be solved in a similar fashion, but I'm concerned about doing things the "right/recommended way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the desired maximum length of the string, what do you expect? [This overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696589%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `MaxLength` attributes takes an integer as argument which specifies the actual maximum allowed length of the string. When you use the [parameter-less constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  it will use the maximum length allowed by the database, not sure why jQuery Validation chose to implement this as -1 though.

Comment: Thanks, I do know that, but I need it to work without specifying an actual max length. You see, EF ensures that the column is created as NTEXT (I believe) if I don't specify a max length value, so I need that.

Comment: Do you use your EF entity as view model as well?

Comment: Nope, but I scaffold my models from the EF entities. That way, they 'inherit' the attributes from the EF entities. I can change the scaffolding logic to add the max length value if it is missing, but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

Comment: You shouldn't do that in my opinion, to avoid such issues.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure I agree. Unless there is absolutely no other better way of handling this issue.

Comment: They serve different purposes, so why would you inherit from each other or create dependencies to each other.