# Validator ignoring MaxLength attributes

Tags: c#

**Problem:**
I am trying to manually Validate some c# objects, and the Validator is ignoring string length related validations.

**Test Case:**
extending [this example](https://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx) which uses the [Required] attribute, i also wanted to validate that strings were not too long, as follows.

```
public class Recipe
{
    //[Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1)] public string difficulty = "a_string_that_is_too_long";
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var recipe = new Recipe();
    var context = new ValidationContext(recipe, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(recipe, context, results);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        foreach (var validationResult in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        } 
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("is valid");
    }
}
```

**Expected result:** an error: "difficulty is too long."

**Actual result:** 'is valid'

other things tested:

- the validator is working, uncommenting the [Required] results in the message "The Name field is required."
- using [StringLength] instead (as noted 
  at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802739/432976 ) made no difference.

Comment: you can change `=` to `=>` to switch it to a property

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes to have the validation work the way you expect:

**1. You have to change the `difficulty` field to a property.**

The `Validator` class only validates properties, so change the `difficulty` definition to a property like this:

```
[MaxLength(1)] public string difficulty { get; set; } = "a_string_that_is_too_long";
```

**2. Specify the `validateAllProperties: true` parameter to the `Validator.TryValidateObject` call.**

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411803(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Validator.TryValidateObject` is not very forthcoming about the fact that, unless you use the overload with `validateAllProperties: true`, only the `Required` attribute will be checked. So modify the call like this:

```
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(recipe,
                                          context,
                                          results,
                                          validateAllProperties: true);
```

Comment: well, i guess that means even their example code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx wouldn't work then ... (that's just a field with the attribute)

Comment: Only issue with this, is that TryValidateObject will now through an exception for other violations. Doesn't seem to "try" very hard.